# How to store URL in table and use as link on table?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I want to implement bookmark. I have problem with saving correct URL, when I store complete URL this link work till session is same as current.

I can store URL as:

```
'f?p=':APP_ID||':'||:APP_PAGE_ID
```

but what to store as a session? Pages are not public.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel - use `APEX_PAGE.GET_URL` instead. For example:

```
select APEX_PAGE.GET_URL (p_page => :APP_PAGE) as URL
from dual;
```

The result is then something like this:

```
f?p=12488:3:109743317382702:::::
```

Live screenshot from apex.oracle.com:

[image]

Comment: Query return: `javascript:apex.navigation.dialog.close(true,function(pDialog){ apex.navigation.dialog...`

Comment: Doesn't for me (lucky me, eh?). **Where** does it return that message? Where did you put it?

Comment: Same when I use in save process I used this code `select APEX_PAGE.GET_URL (p_page => :APP_PAGE) as URL
from dual;`

Comment: I posted a screenshot from apex.oracle.com which shows that it *works*.

Comment: With source works well, but when I logged out I can't use this bookmark again. I got 
message `Your session has ended`

Comment: Thanks for your effort to help me, record in my table is a bit different it's begin with https://

Comment: Well, it can't work when you log out (unless the page URL navigates to is a public page).

Comment: It means that I can't use bookmarks like that?

Comment: If you aren't logged in, then you're a public user (if you check its name, it is "nobody"). As such, you can't authenticate to the database in order to fetch your own bookmark. "Everybody" is "nobody", so you could see everyone's bookmarks. Browser can't reveal any information about yourself (such as operating system user, your IP address and similar) - these data is related to the database server (the one that runs your Oracle database, and Apex resides in it). So - if I understood you correctly - no, you can't use bookmarks like that.

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation, when I logged out and login again, this url link doesn't work I got Your session has ended. Url from bookmarks table works only when current session = url session from link

Comment: Aha. In that case, save only page number, not the whole URL. When you log in again, generate a new URL (using the same APEX_PAGE.GET_URL, pass page ID you previously stored as a parameter).

Comment: Your solution works, but there is a problem with page items, when user save page when item has a value. For instance, Master Detail page.

Comment: You mean, you'd have to store not only page number, but - say - the whole page context, so that they could return exactly where they previously were? If so, I'm afraid that you'll have to save some more info (such as master table's ID, or whatever you might need).

Comment: Yes, I shoud store items name and values. But how to do that? :)

Comment: You'd have to have a table that is capable of holding everything you want to store, I guess.

Comment: How to store just item and item value from url?